# Hashmaps and Dataclasses

Tags: java, hashmap

I am experimenting with HashMaps

I have the following code however i am doing something wrong in that my loop where i am putting in the entries BMW and Renault 6 times into the loop causes an error.

The error is no suitable method found.

```
package javaapplication16;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JavaApplication16 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

for (int index = 0; index <=6; index++){    
hm.put(index,getcarresults("BMW","Renault"));
}

    }

private static CarResults getcarresults(String A, String B){     
return new CarResults(A,B);

}



}
```

and  my class is

```
package javaapplication16;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

class CarResults {
final ArrayList<CarResults> staticsArray = new ArrayList<>();
final HashMap<Integer, ArrayList> myHashMap = new HashMap<>();

   private String foo;
   private String bar;

   public CarResults (String foo, String bar) {
      this.foo = foo;
      this.bar = bar;
   }

   public String getFoo() {
      return foo;
   }

   public String getBar() {
      return bar;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is returning `CarResults` object and not a `String`. Hence, you should change your `HashMap` definition to the following:

```
HashMap<Integer, CarResults> hm = new HashMap<Integer, CarResults>();
```

Or Simply:

```
Map<Integer, CarResults> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: I will accept this thanks for the clarification. I knew it was close. When i try and print out the value stored in position 1 using System.out.println(hm.get(1)); i just get javaapplication16.CarResults@15db9742 why dont i get the value i stored eg. BMW/Renault?

Comment: @MrAssistance That's because `CarResults` is an object. You'll have to override the `toString()` method of `CarResults` to print it's contents.

Comment: @MrAssistance I don't know the end goal here but you can also do something like: `System.out.println(hm.get(1).getFoo());` and `System.out.println(hm.get(1).getBar());`

Answer (score 1):

You have an hashmap which requires a int as key and a string as value, but you try to put a  carresults object as value in the map